# Is it possible to rank span_near queries with unique results higher than duplicate results?

Tags: elasticsearch

Assume I have two documents that have a "catField" containing the following information:

Document one:

```
happy cat
sad cat
meh cat
```

Document two:

```
happy cat
happy cat
happy cat
```

I am attempting to write a query that fulfils two requirements:

1. Find any word with a length of at least three followed by the word "cat".
2. The query should also rank documents with more unique types of cats (document one) higher than those that have the same types of cats (document two).

Here is my initial solution that uses [`span_near`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-near-query.html) with regexp that fulfils the first requirement:

```json
"span_near": {
   "clauses": [
       {
            "span_multi": { 
                "match": { 
                    "regexp": {
                        "catField": "[a-z]{3,}"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "span_multi": { 
                "match": { 
                    "regexp": {
                        "catField": "cat"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   ],
   "slop": 0,
   "in_order": true
}
```

This works great for finding documents with lists of cats, but it will rank Document one, and Document two (above) the same. How can I fulfil that second requirement of ranking unique cat lists higher than non-unique ones?

Comment: Would you be willing to tackle this from an index-time perspective? I think it would be easily doable with some custom analyzer magic.  The problem with span queries (other than being slow) is that they don't play nicely with many of the other queries, which makes differential boosting/sorting hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is an approach using some indexing magic to get what you want.  I'm not entirely certain of your requirements (since you are probably working with data more complicated than just "happy cat"), but it should get you started in the index-time direction.

This may or may not be the right approach for your setup.  Depending on index size and query load, phrase queries/span queries/bool combinations may work better.  Your requirements are tricky though, since they depend on order, size of preceding token, and number of variations.

The advantage of this is that much of your complex logic is baked into the index, gaining speed at query time.  It does make your data a bit more rigid however.

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/cats
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/cats -d '
{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1,
        "number_of_replicas" : 0,
        "index" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "analyzer" : {
                    "catalyzer" : {
                        "type" : "custom",
                        "tokenizer" : "keyword",
                        "filter" : ["cat_pattern", "unique", "cat_replace"]
                    }   
                },
                "filter" : {
                    "cat_pattern" : {
                     "type" : "pattern_capture",
                       "preserve_original" : false,
                       "patterns" : [
                          "([a-z]{3,} cat)"
                       ]   
                    },
                    "cat_replace" : {
                     "type" : "pattern_replace",
                       "preserve_original" : false,
                       "pattern" : "([a-z]{3,} cat)",
                       "replacement" : "cat"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "cats" : {
            "properties" : {
                "catField" : { 
                    "type" : "multi_field",
                    "fields": {
                        "catField" : {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "standard"
                        },
                        "catalyzed" : {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index_analyzer": "catalyzer",
                            "search_analyzer" : "whitespace"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

First we are creating an index with a bunch of custom analysis.  First we tokenize with a keyword analyzer (which doesn't actually tokenize, just emits a single token).  Then we use a `pattern_capture` filter to find all "cats" that are preceded with a word longer than three characters.  We then use a `unique` filter to get rid of duplicates (e.g. "happy cat" three times in a row). Finally we use a `pattern_replace` to change our "happy cat" into just "cat".

The final tokens for a field will just be "cat", but there will be more occurrences of "cat" if there are multiple types of cats.

At search time, we can simply search for "cat" and the docs that mention "cat" more often are boosted higher.  More mentions means more unique types due to our analysis, so we get the boosting behavior "for free".

I used a multi-field, so you can still query the original field (e.g if you want to search for "happy cat").

Demonstration using the above mappings:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/cats/cats/1 -d '
{
    "catField" : ["sad cat", "happy cat", "meh cat"]
}'

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/cats/cats/2 -d '
{
    "catField" : ["happy cat", "happy cat", "happy cat"]
}'

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/cats/cats/3 -d '
{
    "catField" : ["a cat", "x cat", "y cat"]
}'

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/cats/cats/_search -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "match": {
           "catField.catalyzed": "cat"
        }   
    }
}'
```

Notice that the third document isn't returned by the search, since it doesn't have a cat that is preceeded by a type longer than three characters.